# Color grid if values in grid exceed threshold - species distribution in QGIS

Tags: qgis, calculate-values, distribution, species

I have distribution data of a set of species (plants, mosses and lichens: 13 species total) in the Netherlands. 
I made a grid that divides the Netherlands into 1x1 km squares. I am not interested in how many points of a single species are within a square. I used the TomBio addon to transform the species point data into 1x1 km squares, so that they match the grid (i.e. ten points of a species in a gridcell are now one 1x1 km square. Also, one species in a gridcell is now a 1x1 km square).

I want to make an estimate of the distribution of the community these species occur in. Every species has a weighing value related to how much they are bound to the community i want to estimate the distribution of. This means that some species that do occur in the community, but also occur in other communities get a value of 1. Species that occur solely in this community get a value of 10. Of course this is different for each of the 13 species.

Based on the weighing values, i determined a threshold value. i.e, if the sum of weighing values (determined by the species that occur) within a grid cell exceed this threshold, i can assume that the community occurs in that gridcell.

To make the whole story a bit more comprehensible:

```
Species      Weighing value 
A            2       
B            4
C            6
D            6
E            10
```

If the sum of the values in a grid is say twelve or more, I assume the community is present there. See below for a heads example of the attribute tables.

How can I use QGIS to calcuate within a gridcell the value of the sum of the appointed weighing values, and if the threshold is exceeded, the gridcell gets a color?

I know how to count the individual blocks (species) in a gridcell, but I havn't worked out a way to include the weighing values in this process.

[image: attribute table example]

Comment: So each gridcell has attribute table fields, with the count of each species in that cell?

Comment: Yes, thats true. Each grid cell is a seperate polygon if you will. So i can count the numer of points in it, but not the the sum of the values connected to that point.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your data structure. Can you add a screenshot of each attribute table to your question? I don't need to see the entire table, just the names of the columns and a couple lines of data in each table.

Comment: I added it in the main question. I also added a short picture of the 1x1 km grid. 
Species are from the excel list since qgis keeps crashing when i start the TomBio addon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Field Calculator to add an integer field called "present" with this expression:

```
"species_ct_A"*"value_A" + "species_ct_B"*"value_B" + "species_ct_C"*"value_C" + "species_ct_D"*"value_D" = 12
```

This expression will evaluate to either "true" (1) or "false" (0). Cells that meet the threshold value of 12 in the above example will have a "present" value of 1. Cells that don't meet the threshold value will have a "present" value of 0.

If you want cells that meet the threshold value to have a different fill color than cells that don't meet the threshold value, use a categorized style to symbolize the grid layer.

---

I still don't entirely understand your data setup, so this is a generic solution using placeholder field names. You will need to substitute the actual field names from your data for the placeholders.

*Species Count and Weighting Values*: The placeholder field name `"species_ct_A"` represents the counted number of species A in each grid cell. The placeholder `"value_A"` represents the weighing value for species A. Each species has corresponding fields. I assumed that these values are attribute table fields in the grid layer. If they are fields in a different layer, you'll need to retrieve them from that layer. The easiest way to retrieve those values would be to join the other layer to the main grid layer.

- If both grid layers have a shared unique ID value, you can do a regular table join. (Layer properties > Joins).
- If they don't, do a spatial join with the `join attributes by location` algorithm (Vector menu > Data management), with the geometry predicate `equals`.

*Threshold value*: I used a threshold value of 12, as in your example. You can substitute any numerical value here, or a field name if the threshold values are stored in that field.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot!